# Import XML on QGIS, not working LandXML

Tags: qgis, xml

I've a problem importing XML data on QGIS, I tried with the plugin LandXML but I read in some others answer here that probably it doesn't work because it is not  landXML.

Do you know what I could do?

Here the body of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eml:eml xmlns:eml="eml://ecoinformatics.org/eml-2.1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="eml://ecoinformatics.org/eml-2.1.1 http://rs.gbif.org/schema/eml-gbif-profile/1.1/eml.xsd"
    packageId="0c4bf92b-95c9-4a2a-9756-67d98195459f" system="http://gbif.org" scope="system"
    xml:lang="en">
    <dataset>
        <alternateIdentifier>10.15468/4gzrjh</alternateIdentifier>
        <alternateIdentifier>http://ipt.naturalsciences.be/ipt/resource?r=be_rbins_vertebrates_aves</alternateIdentifier>
        <title>Royal Belgian Institute of Natural Sciences Bird collection</title>
        <creator>
            <individualName>
                <givenName>Olivier</givenName>
                <surName>Pauwels</surName>
            </individualName>
            <organizationName>Royal Belgian Institute for Natural Sciences - Department of Scientific Heritage Service</organizationName>
            <positionName>curator</positionName>
            <address>
                <deliveryPoint>Vautierstraat 29</deliveryPoint>
                <city>Brussels</city>
                <postalCode>1000</postalCode>
                <country>BELGIUM</country>
            </address>
        </creator>
        <metadataProvider>
            <individualName>
                <givenName>Thomas</givenName>
                <surName>Vandenberghe</surName>
            </individualName>
            <organizationName>Royal Belgian Institute for Natural Sciences</organizationName>
            <positionName>Data manager</positionName>
            <address>
                <deliveryPoint>Vautierstraat 29</deliveryPoint>
                <city>Brussels</city>
                <postalCode>1000</postalCode>
                <country>BELGIUM</country>
            </address>
            <electronicMailAddress>tvandenberghe@naturalsciences.be</electronicMailAddress>
            <userId directory="http://orcid.org/">0000-0002-9269-6548</userId>
        </metadataProvider>
        <associatedParty>
            <individualName>
                <givenName>Patrick</givenName>
                <surName>Semal</surName>
            </individualName>
            <organizationName>Royal Belgian Institute for Natural Sciences</organizationName>
            <positionName>Head of Section Scientific Heritage</positionName>
            <address>
                <deliveryPoint>Vautierstraat 29</deliveryPoint>
                <city>Brussels</city>
                <postalCode>1000</postalCode>
                <country>BELGIUM</country>
            </address>
            <electronicMailAddress>psemal@naturalsciences.be</electronicMailAddress>
            <userId directory="http://orcid.org/">0000-0002-4048-7728</userId>
            <role>CONTENT_PROVIDER</role>
        </associatedParty>
        <pubDate> 2021-01-25 </pubDate>
        <language>ENGLISH</language>
        <abstract>
            <para>The bird collection of the Royal Belgian Institute of Natural Sciences is made up
                of around 82.000 specimens. It includes a significant collection of skeletons and
                eggs as well as type material for 92 species. It is one of the Institute&#39;s
                oldest collections and for much of the historical material, including the tropical
                birds, the Institute owes thanks to ornithologist Bernard du Bus de Gisignies, the
                first director of the Museum of Natural Sciences in 1848. Alphonse Dubois, who was
                appointed curator of the vertebrate collections in 1869, was the first to describe
                many of De Gisignies’ specimens. In the 1930s Zoologist René Verheyen added a great
                deal of material to the ornithological collections and in particular, an
                exceptionally large collection of Belgian and Central African fauna. The Royal
                Belgian Institute of Natural Sciences Bird Collection contains 100061 digitised
                specimens of 10477 taxa. The following classes are included: Actinopterygii,
                Amphibia Linnaeus, 1758, Aves, Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758, Reptilia Laurenti,
                1768</para>
        </abstract>
        <keywordSet>
            <keyword>DaRWIN</keyword>
            <keyword>RBINS</keyword>
            <keyword>Aves</keyword>
            <keyword>natural history collection</keyword>
            <keywordThesaurus>N/A</keywordThesaurus>
        </keywordSet>
        <keywordSet>
            <keyword>Occurrence</keyword>
            <keywordThesaurus>GBIF Dataset Type Vocabulary: http://rs.gbif.org/vocabulary/gbif/dataset_type.xml</keywordThesaurus>
        </keywordSet>
        <keywordSet>
            <keyword>Specimen</keyword>
            <keywordThesaurus>GBIF Dataset Subtype Vocabulary: http://rs.gbif.org/vocabulary/gbif/dataset_subtype.xml</keywordThesaurus>
        </keywordSet>
        <intellectualRights>
            <para> This work is licensed under a <ulink
                    url="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/legalcode">
                    <citetitle>Creative Commons Attribution Non Commercial (CC-BY-NC) 4.0 License</citetitle>
                </ulink> . </para>
        </intellectualRights>
        <coverage>
            <geographicCoverage>
                <geographicDescription>Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Angola, Antigua and Barbuda, Argentina, Armenia, Aruba, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Bahamas, Belgium, Bolivia, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Botswana, Brazil, Bulgaria, Burundi, Cambodia, Cameroon, Canada, Central African Republic, Chad, Chile, China, Colombia, Comoros, Congo, Costa Rica, Croatia, Cuba, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark, Dominican Republic, DR Congo, Ecuador, Egypt, El Salvador, Estonia, Ethiopia, Falkland Islands (Malvinas), Faroe Islands, Fiji, Finland, France, French Guiana, French Polynesia, Gabon, Georgia, Germany, Ghana, Greece, Greenland, Guadeloupe, Guatemala, Guinea, Guyana, Honduras, Hungary, Iceland, India, Indonesia, Iran, Iraq, Ireland, Israel, Italy, Jamaica, Japan, Jordan, Kazakhstan, Kenya, Kyrgyzstan, Laos, Lebanon, Libya, Luxembourg, Macedonia, Madagascar, Malawi, Malaysia, Malta, Marshall Islands, Martinique, Mauritania, Mexico, Micronesia, Micronesia, Federated States of, Montenegro, Morocco, Mozambique, Myanmar, Namibia, Nepal, Netherlands, New Caledonia, New Zealand, Nicaragua, Niger, Nigeria, North Korea, Norway, Pakistan, Palestinian Territory, Panama, Papua New Guinea, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Poland, Portugal, Réunion, Romania, Russia, Rwanda, Saint Helena, Samoa, Saudi Arabia, Scandinavia, Senegal, Serbia, Singapore, Slovakia, Solomon Islands, South Africa, South Georgia and South Sandwich Islands, South Sudan, Spain, Sri Lanka, St Vincent and Grenadines, Sudan, Suriname, Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands, Sweden, Switzerland, Syria, Tanzania, Thailand, Togo, Trinidad and Tobago, Tunisia, Turkey, Turkmenistan, Uganda, Ukraine, United Kingdom, United States, Uruguay, Uzbekistan, Venezuela, Vietnam, Yemen, Zambia, Zimbabwe</geographicDescription>
                <boundingCoordinates>
                    <westBoundingCoordinate>-179.967</westBoundingCoordinate>
                    <eastBoundingCoordinate>178.24</eastBoundingCoordinate>
                    <northBoundingCoordinate>85</northBoundingCoordinate>
                    <southBoundingCoordinate>-78.159</southBoundingCoordinate>
                </boundingCoordinates>
            </geographicCoverage>
            <temporalCoverage>
                <rangeOfDates>
                    <beginDate>
                        <calendarDate> 1814-09-01 </calendarDate>
                    </beginDate>
                    <endDate>
                        <calendarDate> 2019-01-09 </calendarDate>
                    </endDate>
                </rangeOfDates>
            </temporalCoverage>
            <taxonomicCoverage>
                <taxonomicClassification>
                    <taxonRankName>Class</taxonRankName>
                    <taxonRankValue>Actinopterygii, Amphibia Linnaeus, 1758, Aves, Mammalia Linnaeus, 1758, Reptilia Laurenti, 1768</taxonRankValue>
                </taxonomicClassification>
            </taxonomicCoverage>
        </coverage>
        <maintenance>
            <description>
                <para/>
            </description>
            <maintenanceUpdateFrequency>continually</maintenanceUpdateFrequency>
        </maintenance>
        <contact>
            <organizationName>Biodiversity and Ecological Data and Information Centre - Royal Belgian Institute for Natural Sciences</organizationName>
            <address>
                <deliveryPoint>Vautierstraat 29</deliveryPoint>
                <city>Brussels</city>
                <postalCode>1000</postalCode>
                <country>BELGIUM</country>
            </address>
            <electronicMailAddress>info@bedic.be</electronicMailAddress>
        </contact>
    </dataset>
    <additionalMetadata>
        <metadata>
            <gbif>
                <dateStamp>2022-03-17T18:28:19Z</dateStamp>
                <citation>Pauwels O, Vandenberghe T (2021). Royal Belgian Institute of Natural Sciences Bird collection. Royal Belgian Institute of Natural Sciences. Occurrence dataset https://doi.org/10.15468/4gzrjh accessed via GBIF.org on 2022-03-17.</citation>
            </gbif>
        </metadata>
    </additionalMetadata>
</eml:eml>
```

Comment: there isn't actually any spatial data in there (other than a bbox for the whole world)

Comment: This is a metadata file (https://github.com/gbif/eml-profile), not a data file.  It seems to describe a physical collection, not any digital resource.

Answer (score 5):

If you go to the link inside the `<alternateIdentifier>` tag near the top:

http://ipt.naturalsciences.be/ipt/resource?r=be_rbins_vertebrates_aves

You can use the option `Download data as a DwC-A file`. It is a zip file that needs extracting.

[image]

This includes a tab-delimited text file called `occurence.txt` that can be loaded into QGIS:

[image]

[image]

But many of the records are missing coordinates:

[image]